# Wildfly - Minha aplicação não executa

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Oi, pessoal...quebrando a cabeça há vários dias...

Tenho meu ambiente de desenvolvimento com o Eclipse + Wildfly 8.2.1.
   Importei meu projeto .war, consigo startar o server e ele faz o deploy
   sem erros. O problema é quando eu vou executar login, ele retorna :
   "**HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL**"
   E não alcança o servlet controlador. Fiz teste mudando o método p/GET e
   a mensagem continua a mesma. Como posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score 0):

É porque você está chamando `doPost()` sem implementar `doPost()`. É a implementação padrão do `doPost()` que lança o erro dizendo que o método não é compatível.

Veja mais informações [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297049/http-status-405-http-method-post-is-not-supported-by-this-url-java-servlet)

Por Exemplo:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    doPost(req,res);
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{

    System.out.println("Hola");

}
```

Comment: Por favor, mantenha o uso da língua **Português Brasileiro** nas postagens, o site é brasileiro e Espanhol não é muito familiar aqui.

Comment: Só uma observação: não é obrigatório utilizar português do Brasil, isso [já foi discutido pela comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5/4808). A comunidade é em português, tanto faz se pt-br ou pt-pt.

Comment: Mas ele não tinha escrito nem em português.

Comment: @CypherPotato - Minhas desculpas na tradução - posso ler (um pouco) muitos derivados das línguas espanholas / latinas e não percebi que era português